# Java .net Server syntax issue

Tags: java, syntax, server

Apologies in advance if this seems trivial. We recently started doing Java .net servers and I seem to be getting syntax errors I can't find. I've run this through about 4 or 5 text editors incl. notepad++ but no matter what I do Eclipse seems to be coming up with syntax errors. I did initially have all these in separate files and they worked fine with a main each. Our lecturer wants them in one file because life is fun like that. I'm at my wits end with this, and I know I'm probably going to hit myself over the head when I find where it is but I just can't seem to find any syntax problems.

Still, line 48

"Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

/*
Assignment 7_2016
Student name: 
Student number:
*/
public class Assignment7_2016 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Server Code here ===================================

    //====================================================

    //Code for clients here ==============================

      // write 15 cars to the system
     /* write(new Car("96-D-123456", "Nissan", 35000, 20000, true));
      write(new Car("99-G-345356", "Toyota", 3000, 28000, true));
      write(new Car("00-D-1456", "Ford", 40000, 10000, true));
      write(new Car("05-C-846556", "Hyundai", 65000, 20000, true));
      write(new Car("08-D-156", "Ferrari", 555000, 10000, true));
      write(new Car("10-D-9478", "Lambourghini", 95000, 20000, false));
      write(new Car("01-D-9999", "Maserati", 65000, 70000, true));
      write(new Car("06-WW-14656", "Alfa Romeo", 75000, 60000, true));
      write(new Car("98-D-1256", "Perodua", 37000, 4000, true));
      write(new Car("14-D-15576", "Porsche", 635000, 0, true));
      write(new Car("98-G-125656", "Saturn", 35000, 20000, true));
      write(new Car("08-D-113456", "Mini", 35000, 20000, true));
      write(new Car("99-D-125356", "Skoda", 35000, 20000, true));
      write(new Car("01-G-15656", "Lotus", 35000, 20000, true));
      write(new Car("92-D-125346", "Volvo", 35000, 20000, true)); */

    //====================================================

 }
}

class UpDownCarServer{
    final static int portCar = 1235; // any number > 1024
    Data data = new Data();
    try{
      ServerSocket servesock = new ServerSocket(portCar);
      while (true) {
         // wait for a service request on port portSqrt
         Socket socket = servesock.accept();
         // start thread to service request
         new CarUpDown(socket,data).start();
      }
   }catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}

class Data{
    private ArrayList<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();
    private double totalvalue = 0;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    void add(Car c){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            data.add(c);
            // Add car value to total
            totalvalue += c.price();
        }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }

    boolean search(Car c){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            return data.contains(c);
        }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }

    ArrayList<Car> retrieve(String registration){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            ArrayList<Car> dt = new ArrayList<Car>();
            Car c = new Car("",registration,0, 0, false); //use for search
            for(int j = 0; j < data.size();j++){
          Car c1 = data.get(j);
                if(c1.equals(c)) dt.add(c1);
            }
            return dt;
        }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }

    void sell(Car c){
        lock.lock();
        try{
         if(c.forSale()){ 
          this.totalvalue -= c.price(); 
          data.remove(c); 
         }
         else{ System.out.println("Car not for Sale"); }
        }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }
}

class CarUpDown extends Thread{
      Socket socket;
      Data data;
      CarUpDown(Socket s, Data d){socket = s; data = d;}
      public void run() {
        try{
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
          DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
          int opt = in.readInt();
          if(opt == 0){ //upload
             Car c = new Car();
             c.readInputStream(in);
             data.add(c);
             out.writeBoolean(true);
             socket.close();
          }
          else{ //download
            String registration = in.readUTF();
            ArrayList<Car> lst = data.retrieve(registration);
            out.writeInt(lst.size());
            for(int j = 0; j < lst.size();j++){
                Car c = lst.get(j);
                c.writeOutputStream(out);
            }
            socket.close();
          }
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
     }
}

class CarUploadClient {
    final static int portCar = 1235;
 void write(Car c){
    try{
    Socket socket;
    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),portCar);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeInt(0); //send upload option
    c.writeOutputStream(out);
    boolean ok = in.readBoolean();
    if(!ok)System.out.println("Error");
    socket.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
 }
}

final class Car {
    private String registration;
    private String make;
    private double price;
    private int mileage;
    private boolean forSale;

  public Car(String regn, String m, double pr, int mil, boolean s){
    registration = regn; make = m; price = pr; mileage = mil; forSale = s;
  }
  public Car(){
    registration = null; make = null; price = 0; mileage = 0; forSale = false;
  }
  public String registration(){return registration;}
  public String make(){return make;}
  public double price(){return price;}
  public int mileage(){return mileage;}
  public boolean forSale(){return forSale;}
  public String toString(){
    return " : "+registration+", "+make+", "+price+", "+mileage+", "+forSale+" : ";
  }
  public boolean equals(Object ob){ //equality based on registration
    if(!(ob instanceof Car)) return false;
    Car c = (Car)ob;
    return registration.equals(c.registration);
  }
  //======================================================
  //Methods used to read and write to streams over sockets
  public void writeOutputStream(DataOutputStream out){
    try{
     out.writeUTF(registration);
     out.writeUTF(make);
     out.writeDouble(price);
     out.writeInt(mileage);
     out.writeBoolean(forSale);
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
  public void readInputStream(DataInputStream in){
    try{
      registration = in.readUTF();
      make = in.readUTF();
      price = in.readInt();
      mileage = in.readInt();
      forSale = in.readBoolean();
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}

class CarRetrieveClient {
      final static int portCar = 1235;
       try{
         Socket socket;
         socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),portCar);
             DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         out.writeInt(1); // send download option
         int k = in.readInt(); //retrieve number of matches
         if(k == 0){
            System.out.println("No matches found");}
         else{
          Car c = new Car();
          for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            c.readInputStream(in);
            System.out.println(c);
          }
          socket.close();
         }
       } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UpDownCarServer{
    final static int portCar = 1235; // any number > 1024
    Data data = new Data();
    try{
```

You cannot have executable code (starting with `try`) outside of a method.

Comment: Thank you, really rough day. This is code we got from him, and I just don't have the mental fortitude to spot these things right now but I have a million things to do. Sincerely appreciate it.